# safetensors_rust.SafetensorError: Error while deserializing header: HeaderTooLarge

Tags: python, large-language-model, peft

When fine-tuning a Large Language model (Qwen), there is no .bin ending model files but only .safetensors. The following error occurs when importing this pre-trained model. The specific code and error information are as follows.

code:

```py
def load_state_dict(checkpoint_file: Union[str, os.PathLike]):
    """
    Reads a PyTorch checkpoint file, returning properly formatted errors if they arise.
    """
    if checkpoint_file.endswith(".safetensors") and is_safetensors_available():
        # Check format of the archive
        with safe_open(checkpoint_file, framework="pt") as f:
            metadata = f.metadata()
        if metadata.get("format") not in ["pt", "tf", "flax"]:
            raise OSError(
                f"The safetensors archive passed at {checkpoint_file} does not contain the valid metadata. Make sure "
                "you save your model with the `save_pretrained` method."
            )
        elif metadata["format"] != "pt":
            raise NotImplementedError(
                f"Conversion from a {metadata['format']} safetensors archive to PyTorch is not implemented yet."
            )
        return safe_load_file(checkpoint_file)
```

error information:

```py
with safe_open(checkpoint_file, framework="pt") as f:
safetensors_rust.SafetensorError: Error while deserializing header: HeaderToolLarge
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.